# while creating a data frame with labels using pandas it returns an empty data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

this the code:
as shown when i create this data frame it returns empty i wanna know why.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
books = pd.Series(data = ['Great Expectations', 'Of Mice and Men', 'Romeo and Juliet', 'The Time Machine', 'Alice in Wonderland' ])
authors = pd.Series(data = ['Charles Dickens', 'John Steinbeck', 'William Shakespeare', ' H. G. Wells', 'Lewis Carroll' ])
user_1 = pd.Series(data = [3.2, np.nan ,2.5])
user_2 = pd.Series(data = [5., 1.3, 4.0, 3.8])
user_3 = pd.Series(data = [2.0, 2.3, np.nan, 4])
user_4 = pd.Series(data = [4, 3.5, 4, 5, 4.2])
dat = pd.Series([authors, books, user_1, user_2, user_3, user_4]).to_dict()
book_ratings = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=["authors","books","user_1"",user_2","user_3","user_4"])
book_ratings
```

Comment: Check data as all columns must be of same length. Also you can use [pandas dataframe.from_dict](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html)  to directly create your dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out another solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
books = pd.Series(data = ['Great Expectations', 'Of Mice and Men', 'Romeo and Juliet', 'The Time Machine', 'Alice in Wonderland' ])
authors = pd.Series(data = ['Charles Dickens', 'John Steinbeck', 'William Shakespeare', ' H. G. Wells', 'Lewis Carroll' ])
user_1 = pd.Series(data = [3.2, np.nan ,2.5])
user_2 = pd.Series(data = [5., 1.3, 4.0, 3.8])
user_3 = pd.Series(data = [2.0, 2.3, np.nan, 4])
user_4 = pd.Series(data = [4, 3.5, 4, 5, 4.2])
dat = pd.Series([authors, books, user_1, user_2, user_3, user_4], index=['authors','books','user_1','user_2','user_3','user_4']).to_dict()
book_ratings = pd.DataFrame(dat)
book_ratings
```

OUTPUT:

```
                authors              books     user_1   user_2  user_3  user_4
0       Charles Dickens   Great Expectations    3.2      5.0     2.0      4.0
1        John Steinbeck   Of Mice and Men       NaN      1.3     2.3      3.5
2   William Shakespeare   Romeo and Juliet      2.5      4.0     NaN      4.0
3           H. G. Wells   The Time Machine      NaN      3.8     4.0      5.0
4         Lewis Carroll   Alice in Wonderland   NaN      NaN     NaN      4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get an empty dataframe is, that you are not providing an index to `dat = pd.Series(...).to_dict()`
Therefore you get a numerical index from 0 to 5 and `pd.DataFrame`is not able to find the specified columns in the dict.

I would do it like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

books = pd.Series(data = ['Great Expectations', 'Of Mice and Men', 'Romeo and Juliet', 'The Time Machine', 'Alice in Wonderland' ])
authors = pd.Series(data = ['Charles Dickens', 'John Steinbeck', 'William Shakespeare', ' H. G. Wells', 'Lewis Carroll' ])
user_1 = pd.Series(data = [3.2, np.nan ,2.5])
user_2 = pd.Series(data = [5., 1.3, 4.0, 3.8])
user_3 = pd.Series(data = [2.0, 2.3, np.nan, 4])
user_4 = pd.Series(data = [4, 3.5, 4, 5, 4.2])

book_ratings = pd.DataFrame({
    "authors": authors,
    "books": books,
    "user_1": user_1,
    "user_2": user_2,
    "user_3": user_3,
    "user_4":user_4})

print(book_ratings)
```

Output:

```
               authors                books  user_1  user_2  user_3  user_4
0      Charles Dickens   Great Expectations     3.2     5.0     2.0     4.0
1       John Steinbeck      Of Mice and Men     NaN     1.3     2.3     3.5
2  William Shakespeare     Romeo and Juliet     2.5     4.0     NaN     4.0
3          H. G. Wells     The Time Machine     NaN     3.8     4.0     5.0
4        Lewis Carroll  Alice in Wonderland     NaN     NaN     NaN     4.2
```

With this you can directly specify which series has which column name and you do not have to work around the extra series to generate the dict

`user_1` has less datapoints than the others, make sure that those are representing the first three books, as the rest is filled with NaN in this case